# Asp.net core API returning 404 when using policy based authorization on action method

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, authentication, jwt, asp.net-core-webapi

I am using jwt authentication and policy based authorization. When using the attribute with `[Authorize(Policy = "Admin")]` I get a 404 with even my jwt token contains claim with type 'RoleType'.

Here's my ConfigureServices:

```
 public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
 {

            #region UserLogin Lock

            services.Configure<IdentityOptions>(opts =>
            {
                opts.Lockout.AllowedForNewUsers = true;
                opts.Lockout.DefaultLockoutTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(10);
                opts.Lockout.MaxFailedAccessAttempts = 3;
            });

            #endregion

            #region API Version

            services.AddApiVersioning(config =>
            {
                config.DefaultApiVersion = new ApiVersion(1, 0);
                config.ReportApiVersions = true;
                config.AssumeDefaultVersionWhenUnspecified = true;

                config.ApiVersionReader = new QueryStringApiVersionReader("api-version");
                SwaggerConfig.UseQueryStringApiVersion("api-version");
            });

            
            
            services.AddHostedService<Worker>();
                        services.Configure<Settings>(Configuration.GetSection("Settings"));

            services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
            options.UseSqlServer(Configuration["Settings:DbConnection"]));

            
            services.AddIdentity<IdentityUser, IdentityRole>()
                .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>()
                .AddDefaultTokenProviders();

            services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
             .AddJwtBearer(options =>
             {
                 options.RequireHttpsMetadata = false; 
                 options.SaveToken = true; 
                 options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
                 {
                     ValidateIssuer = true,
                     ValidateAudience = true,
                     ValidateLifetime = true,
                     ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
                     ValidIssuer = Configuration["Jwt:Issuer"],
                     ValidAudience = Configuration["Jwt:Issuer"],
                     IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(Configuration["Jwt:Key"]))
                 };
             });
            services.AddAuthorization(options =>
            {
                options.AddPolicy("Admin", policy =>
                {
                    policy.RequireClaim("RoleType", "Admin");
                });
                            });

            services.AddMvc();
            services.AddControllers().AddNewtonsoftJson(options =>
                    options.SerializerSettings.ReferenceLoopHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore);

}
```

And here is my action method where I am using policy

```
        [Authorize(Policy = "Admin")]
        [HttpGet]
        [MapToApiVersion("1.0")]
        public async Task<ActionResult> GetAllCompany()
        {
            try
            {
                var resultData = await _companyService.GetAllCompany();
                if (resultData == null)
                {
                    return NotFound();
                }
                return Ok(resultData);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                _
            }
            return Ok();

        }
```

It is working fine with tags `[Authorize(AuthenticationSchemes = "Bearer")]` and `[Authorize(AuthenticationSchemes = "Bearer", Roles = UserPolicy.CompanyUsersAndPatients)]` but not with policy

Comment: Are you getting any warnings or errors in the debug console? Have you configured the JWT in the appsettings? How are you generating the JWT?

Comment: I am using Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens to generate tokens, and yes I am getting Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 () [https://localhost:44355/patientlink/Account/AccessDenied?ReturnUrl=%2Fpatientlink%2Fapi%2Fv1.0%2FCompany%2FGetAllCompany].

Comment: 404 means the url is not correct.You need to check your url.

Comment: URL is fine, it is working without authorize attribute.

Comment: It seems that after it authorized failed,it redirects to another url,however, it couldn't vist the url,then you got the 404 error,but it works well with the Bearer scheme,so i think it's related with Identity,would it work well with [Authorize(AuthenticationSchemes = "Bearer",policy="Admin"))]?

Comment: I think you'd better specific the scheme if you registed mutipule  scheme in your app

Comment: Thanks @RuikaiFeng, now it is working with [Authorize(AuthenticationSchemes = "Bearer",Policy="Admin")]